# Kupfer problem focusing when started

Tags: launcher, focus

Kupfer is a great launcher for my not so powerful laptop if only the program would work properly. Every time I bring up the app it will not get focus. So I’ve to press the app first before I can search anything. Surely this is not the way things are suppose to be. Anyone had the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: I got the same problem after upgrading to 14.04. The solution & !(class=Kupfer.py) **WORKED** I am not able to comment or upvote as I have low reputation points. So I had to put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Compiz? Have you tried changing the option

**CompizConfig Settings Manager** → **General Options** → **Focus & Raise Behavior** → **Focus Prevention Level**?

Comment: No I’m not using Compiz. The problem fixed itself btw. Maybe from now on I should wait a week before asking. This is the second time I ask a question here only to have it fixed by itself a few days later.

Comment: Why did you mark my answer as the solution then? :) I certainly do not deserve the bonus reputation here... :P

Comment: Because I figured most people do run Compiz. So your answer might be helpful for those.

Answer (score 1):

For those who *are* using compiz, you can add this to the "Focus Prevention Windows" box:

`& !(class=Kupfer.py)`